# How to go full screen? Quick tap results in a pin drop instead of full screen mode

Tags: android

I used to be able to short tap the screen and it would remove the search and explore bars, but now it drops a pin instead, even if the place I have tapped is in the middle of countryside with no places marked nearby.
I want tapping to remove the search and explore bar margins from top & bottom of screen, so that I can see more area (and more of the route displayed) without zooming out.
How do I get the map to go full screen? This problem only started recently.
Moto G6 Play; android version 9; google maps version 11.59.0705
Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Based on Q&A in link below:

https://support.google.com/maps/thread/200393498?hl=en&msgid=205069651

> swipe up the search bar and you'll get a full map screen.

It's work for me.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).